# delphi Treeview node manipulation

Tags: delphi, treeview

i have this treeview structure :

```
Users
  |_Online
  |_Offline
    |_ user1 --> current status offline 
    |_ user2 --> current status Online
    |_ user3 --> current status offline
    |_ user4 --> current status online
```

what i want to do is when a user is online he will be deleted from offline node and moved to the Online node .
example for user2 and user4 , any help please

many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are using the built in `TTreeView`, then you can call the [`TTreeNode.MoveTo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.MoveTo) method.

```
user2node.MoveTo(onlineNode, naAddChild);
```

If a comment you ask:

> How can I access the offline child nodes in code?

Like so:

```
node := offlineNode.getFirstChild;
while Assigned(node) do
begin
  DoSomething(node);
  node := node.getNextSibling;
end;
```

Comment: thank you . but how can i access to the Offline children nodes in code . 
Like `code For i:=0 to treeview.items.count-1 do `

Comment: OK, I've answered that extra question.

Comment: @randydom basically, you want to store something in node.Data field so that you can verify if the node's data(which should point to a user object from where you can get the state) is "online" within an "offline" node, that logic is what you want to implement if I understand you correctly.